# Find file recursively under Windows (dir /s not suitable)

Tags: windows, command-line, file-search

I need find a file in Windows under command line, but receive results as a table. Similar to windowed version of find, where we have last column, displaying location.

`dir /s` doesn't match this requirement, because it enters each directory and reports this in separate header, leaving file list as usual.

Comment: Probably not possible using the command line. You could build something using PowerShell.

Comment: Would this do:
*Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse c:\ -Filter "filetosearch.exe" | select Directory*

Comment: Maybe:
*Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse c:\ -Filter "filetosearch.exe" | select Directory,Name,LastWriteTime | format-table* etc...

Comment: How about `DIR /A-D /B /S` would that suffice for the need?

Answer (score 38):

You can use **where.exe**

```
where /r c:\windows ntoskrnl.exe
```

or, with wildcards:

```
where /r c:\windows ntoskr*
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I have used Windows' `where` as Unix `which` equivalent for a long time, but I did not know until now that is also (somewhat) capable to replace `find` .

Answer (score 21):

If the headers are the only problem in your case, use the `/B` switch.

> dir `filename.ext` /S /B

A list of all files matching the filename along with their location is printed.

Answer (score -2):

dir *filename*.* /S /B

Finds all the matches for the string filename. Displays src and include files

Comment: Can you explain why you think that answers the question?

Comment: Duplicate of answer given over a year ago by @Pradeep, above