# A better `where` command

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, filesystems, cmd.exe

A very useful command on unix-like systems is the `whence` command (sometimes called `whereis`). This tells you where a binary, source and manual file are located. This is handy for those CRAFT moments where you know a useful tool is on the system *somewhere* but you can't recall where.

Windows it seems has a similar command called `where`. Not sure when this was introduced but it seems to operate in a similar way. The only downside is that it is PATH driven. I could go to the trouble of adding to the path for common commands but a) that is work and b) it could have side effects.

Is there a better command I can lean on without having to trawl the file system myself with `DIR /S` or the like?

Comment: You can use `where` also outside of path for recursive search: https://superuser.com/a/1397682/62676

Comment: Great stuff - thank you. Add this to a batch file called *whereis.bat* et voilà: **@echo off
where /r c:\ %1** 

Comment: But is is still a recursive search which takes a lot of time even on a fast SSD. For searching files I prefer the UI program "Search Everything" which uses the NTFS index. Not sure if it also contains a command-line program.